# Node.js Memory Leak when using jsdom to deserialize JSON to DOM

Tags: node.js, jsdom

We use [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to convert a custom json describing a document into a jsdom document so we can use css selectors to easily modify the document.

Problematically our server leaks memory and periodically runs into an OOME. Analysis leads us to the fact that jsdom is the culprit.

We are currently wondering if we use jsdom in a wrong way. If we cannot solve this issue, we will try [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) instead of jsdom which results in a big effort due to refactoring and testing.

The heap snapshots I took showed that none of the JSDOM objects are collected by the GC. Meaning after two runs there are two JSDOM objects in the snapshot and after 10 runs there are 10 objects.

I have tried to expose the GC to force garbage collection. This did not help.

I have tried using window.close() after deserialization but this did not help either.

We currently use jsdom approximately in the following way:

```
let document = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>').window.document;
// json is the json to be deserialized
deserializeJsonNode(json);

function deserializeJsonNode(node_data, parent_node) {
  if (node_data === null) {
    return null;
  }
  let node;
  switch (node_data.nT) {
    case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
      node = document.createComment(node_data.attribute);
      break;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
      node = document.createTextNode(node_data.attribute);
      break;
    case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
      node = document.implementation.createDocumentType(node_data.attribute);
      break;
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
      node = document.createElement(node_data.attribute);
      break;
    case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
      node = document;
      break;
  }

  if (parent_node) {
    parent_node.appendChild(node);
  }

  var child_nodes = node_data.attribute;
  if (child_nodes) {
    child_nodes.forEach(child_node_data => {
      deserializeJsonNode(child_node_data, node);
    });
  }
  return node;
}
```

I hope someone has any idea in what way we use jsdom wrong or what we can try to further investigate our issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does `deserializeNode` do? and I assume you call `deserializeJsonNode` with `document` as the second param?

Comment: Sorry, I changed some method names before posting. `deserializeNode` called in the foreach loop should be `deserializeJsonNode` aswell. The method calls itself recursively and constructs a DOM out of a given JSON.
The second param is only there for the recursive calls.

Answer (score -1):

after further analysis we found that the problem originated a lot earlier in our program. We were using a Node.js Driver for [Cassandra with version 3.1](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.1/api/class.Client/) and passed the retrieved data to JSDOM afterwards via callback.

It seems the error resulted out of this. After upgrading to version 3.2 of the Cassandra driver and retrieving the data synchronously the error is now gone.

Comment: `retrieving the data synchronously ` ??

Comment: Hey @CodyG. , by this I mean we use the Promis-based API newly added in [Cassandra Driver 3.2] (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.2/api/class.Client/) instead of continuing data processing via callback.

like this: `const result = await client.execute(query, [ id ], { prepare: true });`